# Is it possible to use heredoc inside an if statement?

Tags: php

Is it possible and is it the correct way to code using heredoc inside an if statement  in php?

```
if($selection!='')
{
    $price=getselection($selection,$getprice[$selection]);
    if ($selection<8)
    {
        print 'Please enter the  amount<br />';
        print '<form action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="money1" value="'.$money1.'">';
        print '<input type="text" name="money2" value="'.$money2.'">';
        print '<input type="text" name="money3" value="'.$money3.'"><input type="submit">';
        print '<input type="hidden" name="selection" value="'.$selection.'"';
        print '</form><br>';
            if (($money1!='')&&($money2!='')&&($money3!==''))
            {
                $total=$money1+$money2+$money3;
                $money=getmoney($total);
                $change=getchange($total,$price);
            }
        }
    }
echo '</pre>';
```

I am trying to avoid getting out of the php code, and hopping into html and then back into php again, I was just trying to keep everything on the php script; in addition, using multiple print's is messy, thank you for not flaming.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier to just try it rather than ask the question?

Comment: @Ben Shelock: I really don't understand why people are so unwilling to just try something. If it doesn't work after you try then you ask the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
if (conditional)
{
  $foo = <<<html
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
html;
}
```

I'm not aware of any situation where a heredoc 'will not work'. Just always take care to ensure that the closing statement of the heredoc has no leading characters. In my example `html` closes the heredoc and has absolutely no leading chars including spaces.

Comment: Just wanted to note about having `html;` at the very start of the line. A common mistake is to try to intent it to align with the rest of the code.

Comment: @MitMaro Excellent point. I edited my post just as you made your comment. That's probably the most overlooked and frustrating aspects of heredocs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use heredocs inside `if` statements.